# How to populate a jquery grid using Knockout JS in MVC 4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, jqgrid

I'm new to **ASP.NET MVC** and **Knockout JS**. I have a project requirement as below.

1. I should have a **List<>** in a ViewModel which is the data for my **grid**.
2. I need to pass that List's data from the **Controller** to the
   **view** through a **$.ajax()** method.
3. The data coming from the controller should be in **JSON** format.
4. I should use **Knockout JS** for data-binding in my view.

Please, can anybody help me to do this task with an example or provide me some web links for the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About returning JSON, ASP.Net WebAPI should be you best bet. Some samples here : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

KO Grid could help you doing that on the front-end side. There's some sample here to get you started : http://knockout-contrib.github.io/KoGrid/#/overview

I think that's actually the only things you'll need to get you started!